# Do not submit whole form on ajax action

Tags: jsf, richfaces

Is it possible in `Richfaces 4` not to submit the whole form to server on an ajax action? Does such an attribute or tag exist?

If I have a large form, it makes sense to submit to server only what is needed.

Comment: You're correct in that the entire form is submitted, the server only selects what to run thru the lifecycle based on the settings of `process`/`execute`. It seems wasteful (and probably is), but yeah, that's the state of things. That's why it's best practice to have small, narrowly scoped forms

Comment: [BabbageFaces](http://www.beyondjava.net/blog/introducing-babbagefaces-efficient-ajax-dirt-cheap/) purports to optimize the response, not the request. That's something I guess

Answer (score 0):

Well normally the `execute` attribute (of `a4j:commandButton` for example) is for that purpose. You can also define sections with `a4j:region` to use as a part you want to execute.

**More info**

- [a4j:commandButton](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_X/vdldoc/a4j/commandButton.html)
- [a4j:region](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_X/vdldoc/a4j/region.html)

Comment: I think it still submits the full form to the server. Then on server only the execute part is processed. But still the form is submitted. I will check again, but I think this is the case.